# How does one covert between java.awt.Image and android.graphics.Bitmap

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I simply need to know how to covert an Image of class "java.awt.Image" to a "android.graphics.Bitmap".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do that on Android since the awt packages are not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: Its possible to add the Awt package to a eclipse project.

Comment: But it is not possible to run awt on a Android devices.. so what is your point? Your Eclipse project setup is broken...

Comment: I see..Well thank you. I would ask why, but I don't suppose that it matters.

Comment: Because Android has its own native rendering and drawing subsystem that replaces everything awt does. Even on the JVM awt is largely being replaced by JavaFX...